# VSCode Yellow HTML in JS file

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

How can I make it so my HTML in my JS file is not just yellow? How can I give it Syntax Highlighting in VSCode?

[image: Example]

Comment: Great extensions like: https://github.com/vuejs/vetur will do that for you if you will use the concept of single file components: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

Comment: There are mutliple Extensions that offer this functionality, I would Recommend Vetur: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=octref.vetur or lit-html: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bierner.lit-html

Answer (score 0):

If you separate your code into components and install the following [plugin](https://github.com/vuejs/vetur) It will give you IntelliSense and syntax highlighting for Vue.

See an example here --> https://codesandbox.io/s/o29j95wx9

Good example of it here from the Vue docs --> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html

I think VS code has to see it separated out into blocks below for it to properly do syntax highlighting otherwise it'll just detect what you have declared in the template as strings.

```
<template></template>

<script></script>

<style></style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Install Vue Inline Template in vscode. [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=faisalhakim47.vue-inline-template)